# Is it possible to save the scrollback in Gnome's Terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

So I've run this long, involved difficult test that has a huge amount of output.  This time, some problem has cropped up and I need to search through the output.  To do that, I have to save the thousands of lines of scrollback into a file.  I've tried to capture it with my mouse, but it gets very, very slow and sometimes my finger slips.  I need the output.  There is no obvious way.  The answer, "You should not be going there from here" means that Gnome Terminal is fatally deficient.  I sure hope that is not true.

So, How do I capture the scrollback without scrolling through everything with the #1 mouse button held down the entire time?  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two optinos:

1. use piping:

$> `command > output.txt`

So the complete output will be saved in a file output.txt and then you can open it with a text editor and do whatever you want with the output

```
  2.Set infinite scrolling on gnome-terminal

`Edit->profile-preferences->Scrolling->unlimited scrolling`
```

Then you can search through complete output using `CTRL+SHIFT+F`

hope this helps!

Comment: Even better, use `&>` for piping to catch stderr too.

Comment: And then use, "tail -f" to monitor the mess.  The real fix belongs in Gnome-terminal.  They have the capability, but the maintainer has an aesthetics issue with something or another and has left it disabled by default.  (I ran down the Gnome bug report.)  Anyway, thanks for the "optino" idea.  I just have to remember it before I need it. :)